# Office interop assemblies Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, interop, ms-office, windows-10

I've been trying to download the "office interop assemblies" listed [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508)

But as listed, Windows 10 isn't supported, despite this I tried installing it anyway, and it wont install.

What are my options for Windows 10?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got them working by following these steps:

Ensure that .NET 3.5 is enabled in Windows features under Programs and Features.

Download and install the PIAs as described in the link you mention.

Add the references to your Project. They should be installed under C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\

Answer (score 0):

I followed this steps:

Enabled .NET 3.5 in Windows features under Programs and Features.

Downloaded Office Tools for visual studio 2015:
https://www.microsoft.com/web/handlers/WebPI.ashx?command=GetInstallerRedirect&appid=OfficeToolsForVS2015

(The main site is: https://www.visualstudio.com/pt-br/vs/office-tools/)

Rebuild the solution.